# Swift - Video background is very poor in quality

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avkit

I've managed to load a video as an animated background in my View (using AVKit and AVFoundation).

The code is the following:

```
//MARK: Video background
struct PlayerView: UIViewRepresentable {
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PlayerView>){
}

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
    return LoopingPlayerUIView(frame: .zero)
}
}

class LoopingPlayerUIView: UIView {
private let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
private var playerLooper: AVPlayerLooper?
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "deer", withExtension: "mp4")!
    let asset = AVAsset(url: fileUrl)
    let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    let player = AVQueuePlayer()
    playerLayer.player = player
    playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
    layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: player, templateItem: item)
    player.play()
}
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    playerLayer.frame = bounds
}
}
```

---

```
GeometryReader{ geo in
                ZStack {
                    PlayerView()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height+100)
                        .overlay(Color.black.opacity(0.3))
                        .blur(radius: 1)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5){
                        Spacer()
                        Text("bla bla bla")
                            .font(.system(size: 65))
                            .fontWeight(.black)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
```

Everything works fine but the video is displayed in a very poor quality (the video itself is in 4K).
Is there something I'm missing?
Thanks.